# Explanation on Uniform Coloring, Color-Refinement, and Automorphism Group of Graph

Tags: graph-theory, definition, coloring, automorphism-group

***Translation.***

I am preparing for an exam and need a little bit of help for an exercise below.

> An undirected graph with six vertices is given.  The task is to color the graph.  The task is:
>
> (i) Starting with a uniform coloring on $G$, apply color-refinement on $G$ (multiple times, if necessary) until a stable coloring is achieved.  Specify the coloring of the graph after each run.
>
> (ii) What can you say about the result from Part (i) about the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(G)$?

I know that, in a vertex coloring, two adjacent vertices cannot be of the same color.  What are then a uniform coloring and color-refinement?  When is a stable coloring achieved?  And what are automorphism groups?  Thank you.

---

***Original Text.***

Ich bereite mich für eine Klausur vor und brauche ein bisschen Hilfe bei einer Aufgabe .

> Es ist ein ungerichteter Graph mit $6$ Knoten gegeben und wir müssen ihn färben .  Die Aufgabe lautet :
>
> (i)Starten Sie mit der uniformen Färbung auf dem Grapehn G und wenden Sie ColorRefinement (mehrfach) auf $G$ an, bis eine stabile Färbung erreicht wird . Geben Sie jeweils die Färbung des Graphen an , die nach jedem Durchlauf erzielt wird .
>
> (ii) Was können Sie mit dem Ergebnis aus (i) über die Automorphismengruppe $\text{Aut}(G)$ aussagen ?

Ich weiß also , dass bei einer Färbung müssen nicht zwei adjazent-Knoten die gleiche Farbe haben.
Was ist dann  eine uniforme Färbung und ColorRefinement ? Wann ist eine Stabile Färbung erreicht und was sind Automorphismengruppe ?
Danke

Comment: Welcome to MSE. English is the language that you should use here.

Comment: Ich weiss nicht, was *Color-Refinement* bedeutet.  Aber ich glaube, dass [dieser Text](https://materials.dagstuhl.de/files/15/15401/15401.MartinGrohe.Slides.pdf) Ihre Frage dazu  beantwortet. $$\ $$ I don't know what color-refinement means, but [this text](https://materials.dagstuhl.de/files/15/15401/15401.MartinGrohe.Slides.pdf) should answer your question.

Comment: See page 4 of the text.  All terms color-refinement, uniform coloring, and stable coloring are all there.  $$\ $$  About graph automorphisms, see [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism) or [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphismus#Graphen).